# What is the syntax in JavaScript for MSCSSMatrix.setMatrixValue?

Tags: javascript, matrix, internet-explorer-10

I have the following code, but using the `MSCSSMatrix.SetMatrixValue` can't be filled with the 16 elements of the matrix? The filling of the properties goes well; I can't find any example of instantiating a `MSCSSMatrix`.

```
scale: function () {
    var s = 0.5;
    var el = document.getElementById("containeddiv");
    var matrix = new MSCSSMatrix(el.style.transform);
    matrix = matrix.setMatrixValue("matrix3d(0.5,0,0,0,0,0.5,0,0,0,0,0.5,0,0,0,0,1)");
    matrix.m11 = s
    matrix.m12 = 0
    matrix.m13 = 0
    matrix.m14 = 0
    matrix.m21 = 0
    matrix.m22 = s
    matrix.m23 = 0
    matrix.m24 = 0
    matrix.m31 = 0
    matrix.m32 = 0
    matrix.m33 = s
    matrix.m34 = 0
    matrix.m41 = 0
    matrix.m42 = 0
    matrix.m43 = 0
    matrix.m44 = 1
    el.style.transform = matrix;
},
```

Comment: try to read this it may be useful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453593.aspx
or use canvas setTransform()

Comment: i read that, it only says the parameter must be "A string in the form of an acceptable value for the transform property in CSS." maybe it isnt possble the way i thought.